# How to check if TPM2.0 is owned and if TPM is enabled in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, tpm

Is there any command to check if TPM2.0 is owned (i.e., ownership is taken) and if TPM is enabled on Ubuntu 16.04?

For TPM1.2 this was possible with

```
cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/owned
```

We are using TPM2.0, Intel TXT, Ubuntu 16.04 and DL380Gen10 server

Comment: What do you mean by ''owned''?

Comment: whether the ownership has taken for the TPM2.0 or not.
For TPM1.2 we can check by using #cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/owned.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a TPM1.2 is owned, enabled and active execute the following commands

```
cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/owned
cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/enabled
cat /sys/class/tpm/tpm0/device/active
```

For some reason I never found a TPM2.0 disabled or disactived. To check if a TPM2.0 is owned:

```
tpm2_getcap properties-variable | grep ownerAuthSet
```

Also, if you have owner set, maybe you have to check if your TPM2.0 is in lockout mode:

```
tpm2_getcap properties-variable | grep inLockout
```

Comment: Documentation for the tpm sysfs is available on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ABI/stable/sysfs-class-tpm